# Internal dependency issue in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to run a rust application but some internal dependency issue is breaking, I am new to rust so struggling to fix it. This is the issue.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research , I was able to find a work around.

```
[dependencies]
connectorx = { version = "0.3.1", features = [
    "arrow2",
    "dst_arrow2",
    "src_mysql",
] }
bitvec = "0.22.3"

[patch.crates-io]
# temporary solution to funty@1.2.0 being yanked, we should propose bitvec upgrade to upstream filecoin crates
# tracking issue: https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/funty/issues/7
# bitvec v0.22.0 depends on funty = "~1.2 which has been yanked #1283 
funty = { git = "https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/funty/", rev = "7ef0d890fbcd8b3def1635ac1a877fc298488446" }
```

Reference to the [Github issue](https://github.com/probe-rs/probe-rs/issues/1283)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the message - there is no `funty` with version 1.2. But there is `funty` with version 2.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.1.

It is required by bitvec.

Go into `Cargo.toml` of this package and try to change the `bitvec` (or `funty` if it is there) to a higher or lower version

Comment: It looks like the dependency is brought in by bitvec [requiring ~1.2 here](https://github.com/ferrilab/bitvec/blob/v0/22/3/Cargo.toml#L59) so it might need bitvec to be updated instead.